# Why SFINAE doesn't work?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I want to check that whether the class has operator().
I tryied the following SFINAE.

```
#include <type_traits>  //for std::true_type/false_type
#include <utility>      //for std::declval

template <typename T, typename... A>
class has_call_operator {
private:
    template <typename U, typename... P>
    static auto check(U u, P... p) -> decltype(u(p...), std::true_type());
    static auto check(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());

public:
    using type
        = decltype(check(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<A>()...));
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

At a glance, this is working correctlly.

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    void operator()(const int x) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_call_operator<test, int>::value << std::endl;    //true
    return 0;
}
```

But, the abstract class was not worked correctly by it.

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    void operator()(const int x) {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_call_operator<test, int>::value << std::endl;    //false
    return 0;
}
```

Why does not this code work?
Also, could you make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take `U` by value, so it requires also the construction of the type.

Pass by const reference to fix that.

You may look at [`is_detected`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249985/how-to-require-an-exact-function-signature-in-the-detection-idiom/45250180#45250180) and have something like:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using call_operator_type = decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Ts>()...));

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
using has_call_operator = is_detected<call_operator_type, T, Args...>;
```