# How to require an exact function signature in the detection idiom?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, type-conversion

Let's suppose I have a type `T` and I want to detect whether it has a subscript operator which I can call with with another type `Index`.  The following example works just fine:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template < typename T, typename Index >
using subscript_t = decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<Index>()]);

int main()
{
    using a = subscript_t< std::vector<int>, size_t >;
    using b = subscript_t< std::vector<int>, int    >;
}
```

*However,* I want the function to be detected if and only if the function signature matches exactly.  In the example above I would like the statement `subscript_t< std::vector<int>, int >;` to throw an error like `no viable overloaded operator[]`, because the signature of the subscript operator for `std::vector` is

```
std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>::operator[](size_type pos);
```

where `size_type` in GCC is `unsigned long`.  How can I avoid the implicit conversion from `int` to `size_t` to take place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), you may do:

```
template <typename T, typename Ret, typename Index>
using subscript_t = std::integral_constant<Ret (T::*) (Index), & T::operator[]>;


template <typename T, typename Ret, typename Index>
using has_subscript = is_detected<subscript_t, T, Ret, Index>;

static_assert(has_subscript<std::vector<int>, int&, std::size_t>::value, "!");
static_assert(!has_subscript<std::vector<int>, int&, int>::value, "!");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0898baae33a8aa31)

---

I wrote this in SO Documentation:

#### `is_detected`

To generalize type_trait creation:based on SFINAE
 there are experimental traits `detected_or`, `detected_t`, `is_detected`.

With template parameters `typename Default`, `template <typename...> Op` and `typename ... Args`:

- `is_detected`: alias of `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` depending of the validity of `Op<Args...>`
- `detected_t`: alias of `Op<Args...>` or `nonesuch` depending of validity of `Op<Args...>`.
- `detected_or`: alias of a struct with `value_t` which is `is_detected`, and `type` which is `Op<Args...>` or `Default` depending of validity of `Op<Args...>`

which can be implemented using `std::void_t` for SFINAE as following:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid,
              template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    struct detector
    {
        using value_t = std::false_type;
        using type = Default;
    };

    template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>
    {
        using value_t = std::true_type;
        using type = Op<Args...>;
    };

} // namespace detail

// special type to indicate detection failure
struct nonesuch {
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected =
    typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using detected_t = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::type;

template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using detected_or = detail::detector<Default, void, Op, Args...>;
```

Traits to detect presence of method can then be simply implemented:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using foo_type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(std::declval<Ts>()...));

struct C1 {};

struct C2 {
    int foo(char) const;
};

template <typename T>
using has_foo_char = is_detected<foo_type, T, char>;

static_assert(!has_foo_char<C1>::value, "Unexpected");
static_assert(has_foo_char<C2>::value, "Unexpected");

static_assert(std::is_same<int, detected_t<foo_type, C2, char>>::value,
              "Unexpected");

static_assert(std::is_same<void, // Default
                           detected_or<void, foo_type, C1, char>>::value,
              "Unexpected");
static_assert(std::is_same<int, detected_or<void, foo_type, C2, char>>::value,
              "Unexpected");
```

Comment: I'd mention it's not part of C++11/14.

Comment: It’s not part of C++17 either; it hasn’t been merged yet. It might or might not make it into C++2a.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
template <typename Index, typename ClassType, typename ReturnType>
constexpr bool arg_t(ReturnType (ClassType::*)(Index))
{
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename Index>
struct subscript_t
{
    static_assert(arg_t<Index>(&T::operator[]));
};
```

Note that you'll need to instantiate `subscript_t`, not merely name its type:

```
int main()
{
    subscript_t< std::vector<int>, size_t > a;
    subscript_t< std::vector<int>, int    > b;
}
```

Another way, which lets you determine the exact error message:

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename ArgType>
constexpr ArgType arg_t(ReturnType (ClassType::*)(ArgType))
{
    return {};
}

template <typename T, typename Index>
struct subscript_t
{
    using Actual = decltype(arg_t(&T::operator[]));
    static_assert(std::is_same<Index, Actual>::value, "oops");
};
```